# PHP Array that is returning multiple records

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP Array that is returning multiple records

I am trying to print name, the code below, it displays blank

```
echo $myArr['data'][0]['name'].'.<br />';
```

**Array**

```
[context] => Array
        (
            [myArr] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Steve
                                    [id] => 342342
                                )

                        )

                    [paging] => Array
                        (
                            [cursors] => Array
                                (
                                    [before] => MTA4N3TkyNjk5NTY4OTM0
                                    [after] => MTA4NTk4fyNjk5NTY4OTM0
                                )

                        )

                    [summary] => Array
                        (
                            [total_count] => 1
                        )

                )

            [id] => dXNlcl9jb250ZAXh0OgGQ8R4uxKRXv4TB6RJvkDEQGodfghSqptNeZCeOf3WRldmwoLrZC8qI964vhQqZBS0julEpZAmJuRGZAeZBFMhEWS4vN0gVYMtf4hh6HFXGtjGjm1tKSfuoZD
        )

    [id] => 1010330636443448
```

Comment: And where is `[context][myArr]`?

Comment: `$myArr['context']['myArr']['data'][0]['name']`

Comment: What happened to `context` and `myArr`?  You just ignore those?

Comment: `echo $myArr['context']['myArr']['data'][0]['name'].'.<br />';`

Comment: @tkausl your code worked, thanks.